# EE v2 to v5 upgrade SQL error when selecting channel for editing an entry

Tags: ee2-upgrades

The upgrade from v2 to v5 working without error as did upgrading several plugins, however when in the control panel I and I select 'Edit' > and a channel I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column ‘channel_id’ in where clause is ambiguous:
```

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.author_id, m.screen_name 
FROM (exp_channel_titles t) 
LEFT JOIN exp_members m ON m.member_id = t.author_id 
WHERE channel_id = 83 
ORDER BY screen_name asc
```

Any help identifying the cause of this error and providing a fix would be very much appreciated

Please note: I understand what the error means and how to fix it, what I need to know is what is going wrong and how to fix it in relation to the framework that it's used in Expression Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix I simply removed the `channel_id` field from the `exp_members` table, it didn't have any useful info in it (every row was set to '0') and it isn't needed!

I'm not even sure why/how this column was added to the members table, members aren't really related to channels.